# Popup "Select your next badge" not showing in center

Tags: bug, design, popup

There is an issue with the popup "Select your next badge" that it's not showing in center on zoom in.

On zoom 110%:

[image]

On zoom 100%:

[image]

On zoom 80%:

[image]

It does not show centrally as you zoom in.

And zoom in Chrome is not changed when you set it first.